# SQL Query select top and bottom rows from every batch in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime, greatest-n-per-group

I have a bunch of data as below, which I have already extracted from the DB and already ordered.

```
ExecutionTime            BatchKey   Account   Instrument    UserName
2020-10-16 17:27:03.600     1        1234      ABOK        HornedFrogs
2020-10-16 17:27:03.600     1        EGO321    ABOK        HouseAccount
2020-10-16 21:14:04.483     1        EGO321    ABOK        HouseAccount
2020-10-16 21:14:04.483     1        1234      ABOK        BrokerAccount
2020-10-16 14:28:10.973     2        1098      ABOK        BaylorBears
2020-10-16 14:28:10.973     2        EGO321    ABOK        HouseAccount
2020-10-16 14:28:10.973     2        EGO321    ABOK        HouseAccount
2020-10-16 14:28:10.973     2        1234      ABOK        BrokerAccount
2020-10-16 21:14:04.473     2        EGO321    ABOK        BrokerAccount
2020-10-16 21:14:04.473     2        1234      ABOK        CustodianAccount
2020-10-16 12:26:21.503     3        1098      ABOK        SMUMustangs
2020-10-16 12:26:21.503     3        EGO321    ABOK        HouseAccount
2020-10-16 12:26:21.503     3        EGO321    ABOK        HouseAccount
2020-10-16 12:26:21.503     3        1234      ABOK        BrokerAccount
2020-10-16 21:14:04.377     3        EGO321    ABOK        BrokerAccount
2020-10-16 21:14:04.377     3        1234      ABOK        CustodianAccount
2020-10-16 07:14:04.411     4        1234      ABOK        BrokerAccount
```

The above data is organized by the BatchKey, so everything in a BatchKey is grouped together.

Each BatchKey is sorted by the ExecutionTime, so the earliest one is on the top, and the latest one is at the bottom.

I would like to use this as a smaller table, and extract the rows based on the below logic:

For every BatchKey:

```
-if the BatchKey has more than 2 entries, select the earliest (top) and the latest (bottom) entries in the batch

-if the BatchKey has exactly 2 entries, select them

-(else) if the BatchKey has only 1 entry, select it
```

The result should look like below:

The query should extract the below rows

```
ExecutionTime            BatchKey   Account   Instrument    UserName
2020-10-16 17:27:03.600     1        1234      ABOK        HornedFrogs
2020-10-16 21:14:04.483     1        1234      ABOK        BrokerAccount
2020-10-16 14:28:10.973     2        1098      ABOK        BaylorBears
2020-10-16 21:14:04.473     2        1234      ABOK        CustodianAccount
2020-10-16 12:26:21.503     3        1098      ABOK        SMUMustangs
2020-10-16 21:14:04.377     3        1234      ABOK        CustodianAccount
2020-10-16 07:14:04.411     4        1234      ABOK        BrokerAccount
```

Is there any way to run such query in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by batchkey order by executiontime) rn_asc,
        row_number() over(partition by batchkey order by executiontime desc) rn_desc
    from mytable t
) t
where 1 in (rn_asc, rn_desc)
```

The logic is to rank records having the same `batchkey` by ascending and descending `executiontime`, then to filter on the the top and bottom row numbers. If there is just one record for a given `batchkey`, it gets ranked `1` in both directions.

Comment: What if I already ran a ```(Select * FROM BigDB) X``` to form my datasource table above, could I chain this into your solution? Thanks

Comment: @commentallez-vous: (1) sure: you can include the `row_number()`s in your existing query, or replace `mytable` in the query with your subquery. (2) I gave some explanation in the answer; a simple way to understand how this works is to run the subquery first (without the `where 1 in ...` filtering, and stare at the values in `rn_asc` and `rn_desc`.

Comment: Thanks, one last thing is what does the ```t.*``` mean?

Comment: @commentallez-vous: `t` is an alias for `mytable`. `t.*` selects all columns of `mytable`.

Comment: Thanks!!! I'll give it a try when I get back to office tomorrow!